# comparing characters in string MIPS

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, compare, mips

there I'm currently trying to write a MIPS program that will sort the user inputted String and Bubble sort it. A being the in the front and Z last.

Right now I'm kind of confused on how I can compare each individual character in the string. So for example:

String: Stackoverflow
Compare S and T the first two letters. Since S is belongs in the front it stays and no swap happens.

How would I go about moving onto the next set of characters to compare so T and A would be the next set to compare.

I think I would use the lb (load byte) instruction but I'm not entirely sure of to use the offset correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just increment the offset by 1.

Comment: So would it look like this lb $t1, 1($t0)?
or would it be lb $t1, 4($t0).

Comment: Nvm. Since the string is of arbitrary length, you should increment the base pointer by adding 1 to it as 1 character = 1 byte for ASCII (you may want to copy the base pointer to another register to preserve its original value).

Comment: Mmmm I kind of get what you're saying. So for some clarification, if the string is stackoverflow. I load the first byte which is 'S' into a register, so to load the byte 'T' to another register for compare what should I use for the offset?

Comment: What you do is: (Check the length so that you don't compare with terminating 0), load current byte (e.g. `S`) with offset 0, load next byte (e.g `t`) with offset 1, compare, swap if necessary, then increment the base pointer.

Comment: Oh so it's just 1 for the offset, I was getting confused if I should use 4 but if I remember if 4 would be used for an offset of a word.
Thanks for the clarification and help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reminder, in the loop, you must check whether the current pointer is > than the index (base pointer + length of the string  - 1), or you can also check the value at index (current pointer + 1) equals to 0 (NUL) string terminating character or not.

Make sure you keep a copy of the base pointer somewhere (in register or memory).

In each loop, you will read the character currently pointed to by the current pointer by load byte at current pointer with offset 0, and read the next character by load byte at current pointer with offset 1. Then you can do the comparison and swapping. After that, you increase the current pointer by 1 (since a character in ASCII is 1 byte, you will increase the address by 1 byte only).